# Android display getSize() before API level 13

Tags: android

What would be the equivalent of the getSize() method pre-API level 13? Specifically, I need something that would work with Gingerbread.

```
Context context = getActivity();
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
width=display.getWidth();
height=display.getHeight();
```

when target is >= Gingerbread

Comment: Theses methods are deprecated